# should I create one or many collections in mongodb in order to insert and search faster?

Tags: mongodb

I am fairly new to mongodb. I am creating a web app which allows insert and search for multiple products such as laptop, hard driver, webcamm... My question is should I place all of them in a same collection such as "computer" or should I place each product in their own collection like "laptop", "hard driver", "webcam" so that when user search and insert for a product it will be faster ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you should use one collection per "type" of thing you're storing. It sounds like all the examples you've given above would fall under a product "type" and should be in the same collection. Documents in the same collection need not all have the same fields, though for products you will probably have several fields in common across all documents: name, price, manufacturer, etc; each document "sub-type" might have several fields in common, like hard drives might all have RPM, storage capacity, form factor, interface (SATA2/3, IDE, etc).

The rationale for this advice is that MongoDB queries are performed on a single collection at a time. If you want to show search results that cover the different categories of products you have, then this is simple with one collection, but more difficult with several (and less performant).

As far as query performance is concerned, be sure to create indexes on the fields that you are searching on. If you allow search by product name or manufacturer, you would have an index on name, and another index on manufacturer. Your exact indexes will vary depending on the fields you have in your documents.

Insert speed, on the other hand, will be faster the fewer indexes you have (since each index potentially needs to be updated each time you save or update a document), so it is important not to create more indexes than you'll actually need.

For more on these topics, see the MongoDB docs on [schema design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) and [indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes), as well as the [presentations on 10gen.com](http://www.10gen.com/presentations) from 10gen speakers and MongoDB users.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to start with one collection. It is much simpler to search through the one collection rather then collection per product. And in the future if you queries against collection become slow you can start thinking about how to speed up them.

Mongodb has fairly fast [indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes) and it was design to be scalable, so once you will need scale your database -- [replica sets](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets) and [auto sharing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding) in place.